# How do I control where Ember.js appends the rendered application template?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to switch my Ember application over to using the Ember.Router but am having an issue with where the application template gets appended. When I call App.initialize() it renders the template at the end of the document. Is there a way to specify where the rendered application template gets appended to?

My application is a rails app and I'm trying to embed an Ember application on one of my pages. I don't want to change the way my current header and footer gets rendered so ideally I would be able to specify where ember renders the template.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtremaine/vAxkL/2/) example. You can see that it renders:

```
Header Content 
Footer Content 
Test 1 
Test 2 
Test 3
```

What I'm trying for is:

```
Header Content
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Footer Content
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the `rootElement` property of the `Ember.Application`: http://jsfiddle.net/vAxkL/3/

Doc: http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Application.html

**EDIT** -- Fixed the fiddle by anchoring to the 1.0.pre version: http://jsfiddle.net/vAxkL/11/

Comment: Not sure why but I had to do **rootElement: '#application'** rather than **rootElement: $('#application')**

Comment: Worth also mentioning that when you use a rootElement other than body, anywhere you call append() on a view needs to be changed to appendTo('#id-of-your-root-element') or Ember fails in some strange ways.