# In Ember, Using Router, how do I load the Application View into existing html element (like div)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I control where Ember.js appends the rendered application template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321145/how-do-i-control-where-ember-js-appends-the-rendered-application-template)

I have an existing application (not in ember) and I am converting it page by page.
so for the transition period, I need to be able to load the ember application into some container on the existing app, and have it function normally , like accept events, etc.

[made up a small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xFWgj/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12321639/363073

Comment: @pauldechov please mark the question as a duplicate or form an answer if it is not obvious from the reference so this question may be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
App = Em.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#emberPage'
});
```

Keep mind `Ember.EventDispatcher` will only listen inside that root element, so remember that if during your transition you are trying to get ember to respond to clicks in your non-ember portions of the page.

Comment: Working fiddle to support the answer http://jsfiddle.net/xFWgj/1/

Comment: do we have a similar option on a view object (like appendTo) when this view is created by the router ?